# R Merge two dataframes with same columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Imagine you have two dataframes in R, for example. Imagine that columns could have any kind of names, not always a or b. Also there could be much more columns, dozens or even hundreds.

```
a <-
  data.frame(
    id = seq(1, 4),
    a = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
    b = c(3, 3, 1, 1)
  )


b <-
  data.frame(
    id = seq(1, 4),
    a = c("0%", "0%", "50%", "50%"),
    b = c("37.5%", "37.5%", "12.5%", "12.5%")
  )
```

I'd like to merge it to following result:

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    id = seq(1, 4),
    a = c("0 (0%)", "0 (0%)", "1 (50%)", "1 (50%)"),
    b = c("3 (37.5%)", "3 (37.5%)", "1 (12.5%)", "1 (12.5%)")
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a join with some string-concatenation:

```r
library(dplyr)
full_join(a, b, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with(".x"), ~ sprintf("%s (%s)", .x, pick(sub("x$", "y", cur_column()))[[1]]), .names = "{sub('.x$', '', .col)}")) %>%
  select(-matches("\\.[xy]$"))
#   id       a         b
# 1  1  0 (0%) 3 (37.5%)
# 2  2  0 (0%) 3 (37.5%)
# 3  3 1 (50%) 1 (12.5%)
# 4  4 1 (50%) 1 (12.5%)
```

It's certainly possible to do this in base R or `data.table`, if needed, though with a little more code.

```r
tmp <- merge(a, b, by = "id")
tmp
#   id a.x b.x a.y   b.y
# 1  1   0   3  0% 37.5%
# 2  2   0   3  0% 37.5%
# 3  3   1   1 50% 12.5%
# 4  4   1   1 50% 12.5%
xs <- grep("\\.x$", names(tmp))
ys <- grep("\\.y$", names(tmp))
Map(function(m, n) sprintf("%s (%s)", m, n), tmp[,xs], tmp[,ys]) |>
  setNames(sub(".x$", "", xs)) |>
  cbind(tmp[,-c(xs, ys), drop=FALSE])
#         2         3 id
# 1  0 (0%) 3 (37.5%)  1
# 2  0 (0%) 3 (37.5%)  2
# 3 1 (50%) 1 (12.5%)  3
# 4 1 (50%) 1 (12.5%)  4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `powerjoin`'s conflict parameter to apply a function on non-keyed columns with identical names:

```r
powerjoin::power_inner_join(a, b, by = "id", conflict = \(x, y) paste0(x, " (", y, ")"))
#   id       a         b
# 1  1  0 (0%) 3 (37.5%)
# 2  2  0 (0%) 3 (37.5%)
# 3  3 1 (50%) 1 (12.5%)
# 4  4 1 (50%) 1 (12.5%)
```

---

In the case of your example, where dimensions are identical and dataframes are sorted the same way, you can use `==` and `paste` for a vectorized (and more efficient) solution:

```r
amat <- as.matrix(a); bmat <- as.matrix(b)
ifelse(amat == bmat, amat, paste0(amat, " (", bmat, ")")) |> 
  as.data.frame()
#   id       a         b
# 1  1  0 (0%) 3 (37.5%)
# 2  2  0 (0%) 3 (37.5%)
# 3  3 1 (50%) 1 (12.5%)
# 4  4 1 (50%) 1 (12.5%)
```